# SSMS won't let me create spatial index in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, spatial-index

I have already created a spatial index on table FOO, which is working properly, and now I'm trying to create an identical spatial index on table BAR.

```
Table BAR:
id int pk autoincrement,
geo geography,
lat float,
lon float,
someOtherValue int
```

The table contains values that look like this:

```
1   0xE6100000010CD8614CFA7BAF45400AA2EE0390F153C0  43.370971   -79.774415  123456
```

The `TesselationScheme` in the spatial index on FOO.geo is `Geography grid`. Cells per object is 64. The granularity is set to High for each of the four Grid levels. Trying to do the exact same thing with table BAR. Getting this error:

```
Either the object or one of its properties is not supported on the target server version.
```

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60+((SQL11_RTM).120210-1917+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Index&LinkId=20476

But that page at microsoft.com has no info.

Comment: What happens if you use proper DDL (`CREATE INDEX`) instead of fumbling through the GUI? It may be some kind of limitation in the UI or you may be pointed at the wrong server...

Comment: T-SQL DDL works ok.  Hard to believe that after all these years SSMS is still not rock solid.  It's pointed at the right server :-)